# Loading LSB first or MSB first?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, embedded, c

I am trying to create a delay function similar to `builtin __delay_ms()` in MPLABX IDE PIC18F4520.

The question is if I write the LSB first to the TMR0L register, I am not getting the expected delay. Instead of 500 ms, I getting more than a 5 second delay. But when I write the MSB byte first to TMR0H and the LSB next to TMR0L, I am getting a perfect delay.

Even though I am starting the timer only after completely loading TMR0 register, why does it make a difference? What is internally going on which is messing with my preloading of the register? Is it due to compiler optimization?

```c
    //LINK SECTIOM
    #include <xc.h>

    //OPERATIONAL MACROS
    #define BIT(X) (1 << X)
    #define SETBIT(REG,VALUE)       (REG |= BIT(VALUE))
    #define CLRBIT(REG,VALUE)       (REG &= ~(BIT(VALUE)))
    #define TOGGLE(REG,VALUE)       (REG ^= BIT(VALUE))
    #define WRITE_REG(REG,VALUE)    (REG = VALUE)
    #define COMPARE(REG,VALUE)      (REG & BIT(VALUE))

    //SETUP MACROS
    #define _XTAL_FREQ 10000000UL
    #define PRESCALE 256U
    //#define BIT_RESOLUTION 16
    #define delay_ms(X) delay_ms_func((uint16_t)(65535 - (((X) * (_XTAL_FREQ / (PRESCALE * 4000.0))))))


    //GLOBAL DECLARATION SECTION
    inline void delay_ms_func(uint16_t);

    //MAIN SECTION
    void main ()
    {
        CLRBIT(TRISB, 0);
        CLRBIT(LATB, 0);

        while (1)
        {
             delay_ms(500);
            SETBIT(LATB, 0);
            delay_ms(500);
            CLRBIT(LATB, 0);
        }
    }

    inline void delay_ms_func(uint16_t time)
    {
        WRITE_REG(INTCON,0X00);
        WRITE_REG(T0CON,0X07);
        TMR0H = (uint8_t)(time >> 8);   // ----------------> WHY MSB FIRST???
        TMR0L = (uint8_t)(time & 0xFF);

        SETBIT(T0CON, 7);

        while (!TMR0IF) {}
        TMR0IF = 0;
        CLRBIT(T0CON, 7);
        WRITE_REG(TMR0L, 0x00);
        WRITE_REG(TMR0H, 0x00);
    }
```

Answer (score 17):

Maybe chapter 11.2 of the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/PIC18F2420-2520-4420-4520-28-40-44-Pin-Microcontrollers-with-XLP-Technology-30009613F.pdf) points you in the right direction:

> The high byte is updated with the contents of TMR0H when a
> write occurs to TMR0L. This allows all 16 bits of Timer0
> to be updated at once.

I have no experience with this architecture, but it appears to me that a write to TMR0H doesn't actually write the high-byte of the timer register, but a temporary register that gets transferred to the high byte when a write to TMR0L occurs. So TMR0H needs to hold the desired content **before** TMR0L is written.

See also Figure 11-2 in the datasheet.

Comment: Yup. Because you *can* update the values while the timer is running, and they wouldn't want glitches from the hardware observing a "half-updated" value, so there has to be some way to latch a complete 16-bit value into the timer at once. Rather than requiring a *third* write to do the latch, they just had it trigger on the write of the low byte. ezpz.

Comment: Yep. It's a technique with its downsides - it can cause havoc if a task is interrupted in between the write of the high byte and low byte, for instance - but is nevertheless relatively common in embedded systems.

Comment: Thank you for the reference I got it!!!

Answer (score 7):

That's the way the hardware works.

You set the timer into 16-bit mode.

The high byte is written into a temporary register and the whole 16 bits is loaded to the timer when low byte is written.

So if you don't define the high byte, and only write the low byte, you get random garbage written as the high bits.

You must do the correct sequence of writing the high byte first and then the low byte.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I got the point  !! one more thing, Is this the case only with I/O registers or with any 16bit register. I mean the sequence of write operation and use of temporary register.

Comment: @MadhanGasikanti I am sure the datasheet will tell you when it is important to do something in the correct order, like in this case when loading a 16-bit timer register with a 16-bit value.

Comment: @MadhanGasikanti The 6526 CIA chip, used in the Commodore 64, has Time of Day registers representing hours, minutes etc. that also have to be written in a specific order before a new time is set. So i guess this feature could be found on anything that sets some time instant (current or future) across multiple registers.

Comment: @ris8_allo_zen0 It is not related to time in any way, it is related to loading 16-bit or larger registers atomically via 8-bit bus.